# Template class function pointer type alias

Tags: c++, templates, typedef, pointer-to-member

I am trying to make a type alias for a function (myFunction) inside myClass.

```
template<typename T>
using calc_t = matrix<T> (MyClass<T>::*myFunction)(const matrix<T> &X);
```

Where I would get a generic syntax error, `missing ')' before MyClass<T>::*myFunction`.

And then using it as so

```
calc_t<double> fptr = &MyClass<double>::myFunction;
```

I am not sure on the syntax to use in this specific case for when using the `using` type alias as opposed to a non-templated typedef.

I have looked at the following other SO questions that don't seem to cover this specific usage:

- [Function pointer to member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402579/function-pointer-to-member-function)
- [Function pointer type not recognized inside template class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17828489/function-pointer-type-not-recognized-inside-template-class)

I have tried some other variants but to no success.

Comment: Do you get an error? What is the error? A [MCVE] with the class definition would be useful.

Comment: I really recommend against using pointers to member functions (or pointers to *any* function). Instead I suggest using the more generic [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function).

Comment: @clcto I have added the type of error I get in this case.  

You are right. I might port it over the std::function, once I understand this a bit more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative, and as I already suggested in a comment, you could use [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) as it will be easier to use *and* more generic.

```
template <typename T>
class matrix { };

template <typename T>
class MyClass
{
public:
    matrix<T> myFunction(matrix<T> const&) { return {}; }
};

template<typename T>
using calc_t = std::function<matrix<T>(matrix<T> const&)>;

int main()
{
    MyClass<double> myObject;

    using namespace std::placeholders;  // For e.g. _1
    calc_t<double> myFunction = std::bind(&MyClass<double>::myFunction, myObject, _1);

    matrix<double> myFirstMatrix, mySecondMatrix;
    myFirstMatrix = myFunction(mySecondMatrix);
}
```

As shown above, you could use [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind). But you could also use [lambda expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda):

```
calc_t<double> myFunction = [&](matrix<double> const& m)
{
    return myObject.myFunction(m);
};
```

Or better yet (for this simple use-case anyway) use type-deduction

```
auto myFunction = [&](matrix<double> const& m)
{
    return myObject.myFunction(m);
};
```

With lambdas, type-deduction and templates you can create very generic and expressive and complex code in a simple way.

Comment: That is a really great and thorough answer. I have just been dabbling with `std::function` and it definitely seems to be something I should be using. Thanks for explaining how to improve my code!

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the issue is that you are trying to name the function pointer on the right side as well. The following compiled for me:

```
template <typename T>
class Matrix { };

template <typename T>
class MyClass
{
public:
    Matrix<T> myFunc() { return {}; }
};

template <typename T>
using my_f = Matrix<T> (MyClass<T>::*)(); // NOTE: No myFunction here

int main() {
    my_f<double> f = &MyClass<double>::myFunc;
    return 0;
}
```

https://www.ideone.com/VdazMB

Comment: Ah, I think that is it. I'm just going to check through my code to see it all works, then I'll accept the answer. Thank you very much. I did try a similar approach but didn't use :: which is why it didn't work for me.